# having trouble with code to find the presnceof string in a string array in android?

Tags: android

```
String[] s1={"o","c","a","b","ab"};
String ser=new String();
ser="ab";
```

I want to check if my string is present in that string array.please provide me code for that in my android project.
How can check if it is a email id.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `contains()` method of `Arrays` class:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(s1).contains(ser);
```

Comment: How can i check if it is a email id??

Comment: @user2999533 could you give more details what u mean by email id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String x : s1){
   if (x.equals(ser)){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the token use `indexOf()`

```
   java.util.Arrays.asList(s1).indexOf(ser);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.asList(s1).contains(ser);
```

Comment: @BarlasApaydin why doesn't this provide an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(s1);    
if(wordList.contains(ser))
  return true;
else
  return false;
```